# How to pass variable in PL/SQL block statement inside the UNIX shell script

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, plsql

How to pass variable in PL/SQL block inside the UNIX shell script. Here is the ex-

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
declare -a arr=("01", "03", "05", "07", "09", "11")

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do

$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s <<EOF
scott/tiger
set serveroutput on
declare
  id   = &1
  var    .........;
begin
 for i in (select .... from ..... where id = &id);
 loop
  select * from ..........;
  <pkg>.<sp>(var);    -- calling to execute job then process will do
 insert into ....... values(&id, ........);
 end loop;
end;
```

In the `&id` at the time of run this anonymous **PL/SQL** block statement this value will be vary like 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11 like this. It means for every ID this PL/SQL block will run automatically using this Shell script.

For ex, if i run separate PL/SQL block in the SQL developer then for id = 01

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  var    .........;
begin
 for i in (select .... from ..... where id = 01);
 loop
  select * from ..........;
  <pkg>.<sp>(var);    -- calling to execute job then process will do
 insert into ....... values(01, ........);
 end loop;
end;
```

Then same for rest of the ID this shell script should be run automatically.

Comment: not clear exactly what you are asking, but do you mean have shell code `id="01"` set before the first line `$ORACLE_HOME/... .... <<EOF`  and then later you can have `where id = "$id"` and later still `values ($id,....)` ? Just do that and it should work. (I don't see the required closing `EOF` in your first sample code). Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based solely on your example of id=01 (ie, `01` does not need to be quoted) ...

```
# for a single id value

id=01

$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s <<EOF
scott/tiger
set serveroutput on
declare
  var    .........;
begin
 for i in (select .... from ..... where id = ${id});
 loop
  select * from ..........;
  <pkg>.<sp>(var);
 insert into ....... values(${id}, ........);
 end loop;
end;
EOF

# for a series of id values

for id in 01 03 05 07 09 10 11
do

$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s <<EOF
scott/tiger
set serveroutput on
declare
  var    .........;
begin
 for i in (select .... from ..... where id = ${id});
 loop
  select * from ..........;
  <pkg>.<sp>(var);
 insert into ....... values(${id}, ........);
 end loop;
end;
EOF

done
```

What I'm not sure about is the purpose of the leading zero in `01`; if the `id` column is a character datatype then we'll need to update the above examples and change `$(id)` to `'${id}'`.

Comment: Thanks Mark to get the answer but instead of `while` `for loop will apply in the above code.

Comment: arg ... yeah, of course; had started out with a `while ... do ... done < <(get_list>)` construct and then decided for easier `for` but forget to switch out `while` and `for`; thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can even separate code for better organize your code base:

**run.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
for id in 01 03 05 07 09 10 11
do
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s SCOTT/TIGER @proc.sql $id
done
```

**proc.sql**

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  l_id  number := &1;
  var    .........;
begin
 for i in (select .... from ..... where id = l_id);
 loop
  select * from ..........;
  <pkg>.<sp>(var);    -- calling to execute job then process will do
 insert into ....... values(l_id, ........);
 end loop;
end;
/
exit -- exit SQL*Plus
```

All arguments passed to a SQL script can be accessed by their position using `&1, &2, &3`, etc...

Notice `&` is for substitution variables, so if you are passing `varchar2` types, you must enclose them in quotes like `'&1' '&2' '&3'`.

`l_id  varchar2(100) := '&1';`

Notice also if the string you are passing contains a single quote, this can breake your syntax, so you can use this notation to avoid such issue.

`l_id  varchar2(100) := q'(&1)';`

Comment: Thanks Massimo for give me the answer but I've one doubt. How we pass the array variable inside the PL/SQL block statement because for every variable that mentioned above PL/SQL block will execute.

Comment: I've just review the example according to your needs